# LACP and VLAN routing correct network setup

Tags: networking, routing, freebsd, vlan, truenas

I am trying to understand the correct way to do LCAP with a VLAN and have all the routing be correct.

**Hardware**

```
OS:FreeNAS-11.2-U7
Server:(2) Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v3 @ 2.60GHz  
        128GB of ECC RAM
        Intel X540T2 network card
        (2) CAT 7 cables 
Router/Firewall: Ubiquiti EdgeRouter 6P
Switch: Netgear GS752TP 52 port switch
```

**My current setup**

**Router**

What I did was go into the router and add a `VLAN Interface` and set the VLAN id to be `45` with an IP range of 172.16.213.1/24. Then I went to `Services` and set up a new DHCP service with a subnet of 172.16.213.0/24. Then I set up a firewall rule to accept local traffic
[image]
[image]

**Switch**

In the switch, I went to `Switching` and then `LAG`and set up LACP on ports 45 and 47. Then went over to `VLAN` and created VLAN 45. Then went to `VLAN Membership` and assigned LAG CH1 to Trunk and port 2 to Trunk (Port 2 is the port back to the router on the switch)
[image]
[image]
[image]

**FreeNAS Box**

I created a `Link Aggregation` interface using the 2 ports on the card called lagg0. And didn't assign any static IP or DHCP request to that interface. Then I created a VLAN interface called vlan45 using the ID of 45 and NIC interface as the lagg0 interface created earlier. Then set a static IP of 172.16.213.100/24 for the vlan45 interface.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to say I have this set up is currently working but I don't believe it is the correct way or I am missing a step somewhere. This is because when I am trying to type in the IP address of the server it takes exactly 1 min 33 seconds (timed it multiple times) to load the windows authentication pop up where the user can type in their login information to be able to access the file server. If the user has logged in before it pops up almost immediately.

If I assign the lagg0 interface to use DHCP and set the global nameserver to be 10.0.0.1 it will acquire an IP on our main network and then if the user tries to log into the file server the windows authentication pop's up almost immediately.
[image]

I am very confused as to how to set this up to use only vlan45 and have the windows authentication pop up immediately. I hope I am close and it is a step that I am missing. I have been searching for a while now and I can not seem to get anything to work how I would like. I have been playing to static routes on the firewall and the switch but so far nothing seems to help. Thank you for your time and your help on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! From the original post, I was very close and only missed one step, but I feel this step was important and I was not able to find it in any guides or tutorials. I wanted to follow up and hopefully, this is useful for someone else that could be going through the same issue.

The step I missed was to manually set a static route inside of my router. The terminology was a bit miss leading. The destination has to be set to the current network in my case 10.0.0.0/24 then the route type should be "gateway" and the "next hop" the static ip of the server that you want to connect to. I will post a photo below.

It is also worth mentioning that the net gear switch did this routing inside of it automatically. If you are having this issue, please check both

[image]